# Error while using ToString("Format") method

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I have one my_Account page. and for data retrieving i'm using ToString("DD/MM/yyyy") format and i'm also checking in advanced if null but there is one compile time error occurred like

```
Error   48  No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments   F:\EasyWeb\EndUser\My_Account.aspx.cs   59  55  F:\EasyWeb\
```

here is my code:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var query = from u in db.Users
                where u.Username == user_id
                select u;
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Session["Username"] = user_id;
                    hidden_profile_id.Value = item.Id.ToString();
                    lbl_user_id.Text = item.Username.ToString();
                    Bind_DDL_Title();
                    ListItem item1 = drp_title.Items.FindByText(item.Title);
                    if (item1 != null)
                    {
                        item1.Selected = true;
                    }
                    txtf_name.Text = item.First_name.ToString();
                    txt_lname.Text = item.Last_name.ToString();
                    dob.Text = item.Birth_date.ToString("DD/MM/yyyy");
                    if (item.Anniversary_date != null)
                    {
```

//Line 48 No Overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' argument...
                         txt_adate.Text = item.Anniversary_date.ToString("DD/MM/yyyy");

```
                     }
                     Bind_DDL_Status();
                     ListItem item2 = DDL_StatusList.Items.FindByValue(item.status_id.ToString());
                     if (item2 != null)
                     {
                         item2.Selected = true;
                     }
                     txt_email.Text = item.email.ToString();
                     txt_mno.Text = item.mobile_no.ToString();
                     txt_phoneno.Text = item.phone_no ?? "".ToString();
                     txt_address.Text = item.Address ?? "".ToString();
                     Bind_DDL_Countries();
                     ListItem item3 = DDL_CountryNames.Items.FindByValue(item.country_id.ToString());
                     if (item3 != null)
                     {
                         item3.Selected = true;
                     }
                     Bind_DDL_States();
                     ListItem item4 = DDL_StateNames.Items.FindByValue(item.state_id.ToString());
                     if (item4 != null)
                     {
                         item4.Selected = true;
                     }
                     txt_city.Text = item.city_name ?? "".ToString();
                     txt_zip.Text = item.pin_code ?? "".ToString();
                     CompareValidator1.ValueToCompare = item.password.ToString();
               }
 }
```

Please help me...

Comment: What is the *type* of `Anniversary_date`? That type does *not* have a method with a signature like `string ToString(string)` - look at the API to resolve disagreements.

Comment: Also, please fix `"".ToString()`. That's just terrible. `""` *is* a string; or use `string.Empty` if it makes you feel fuzzy inside.

Comment: type of Aniversary_date is Datetime

Comment: No, Aniversary_date is *not* a DateTime. What type *is* it really? Check your assumption and try again. Because a DateTime [*does*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) have such a method overload; but, for instance, a string [does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.ToString(v=vs.110).aspx). Again, *consult the documentation to resolve disagreements*.

Comment: from DB side i user Aniversary_date as datetime and Birth_Date also. how ever one is allow null to aniversary_date.

Comment: It *doesn't matter* what it is in the DB. What *type* is the `Aniversary_date` variable? Let the IDE help you - mouse over the variable where it is used. What does VS say the type is? Once you've resolved that, then you can progress.

Comment: DateTime? User.Anniversary_date here User is table entity and Anniversary_date as properties of that.

Comment: What *type* is the "property" with the name `Anniversary_date`? (It's still not a DateTime.) See how we're just going around in a circle and getting nowhere? Have a good night.

Comment: wat type u mean datatype ok and it's DateTime.

Comment: Let's try this again. *If* `Anniversary_date` *was* a DateTime, *then* it would have the method [string ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx). However, your error message says it does not. Therefore, `Anniversary_date` is *not* a DateTime. Don't fight it. Just find out *what* it really is, and why.

Comment: i'm using LinqToSQl classes ok. now i'm showing Table Named User that have properties like field First Name , Last Name blahh..blahh. here Anniversary_date field(Table Member Property) have Type as System.DateTime. so here why should it's give me this error. how ever this method is working fine to other field like BirthDate....

Comment: Well, here is a simple test. Replace the failing code with: `DateTime anniversary = item.Anniversary_date; txt_adate.Text = anniversary.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` - What happens?

Comment: following ans is right and i'm using it thank u..

Comment: The answer is not "correct" (although it will work for various reaons) and it does not counter anything I have said above. **Your assertions are wrong.** Until you understand that (and why), your code is also wrong.

Comment: here i have to use   DateTime anniversary = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Anniversary_date); and this give's default date like 01/01/1901

Comment: if this item have null value therefore it's gives the default date.

Comment: ".. can't make a horse drink water". When you understand what I have said above, then you will have learned something about the problem and the solution. (Hint: It has nothing to do with "null" values.) Have a good night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use `ToString("DD/MM/yyyy")` in DateTime or Date Object only not all objects.

Try like this

```
dob.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Birth_date.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: All the clout to you.  What an irritating pain it was to find this solution.. glad I learned something though.  Thank You.